# while calling constant value getting error

Tags: php, yii

In root index.php:

```
"Yii::createWebApplication($config);
define('UPLOAD_DIRECT',Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/upload_folder/');
Yii::app()->run();"
```

In controller I am calling this constant while uploading image under create function, like

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs(UPLOAD_DIRECT.$fileName);
```

while uploading I am getting error as " Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_DIRECT - assumed 'UPLOAD_DIRECT' ".

I am new to yii framework can anyone help me to sort out this.

Thanks waahi. :blink:

Comment: Can you try again with `define` line before `Yii::createWebApplication($config);` line? (just use it with some static path for test)

Comment: With static its working perfectly , i need it to be dynamic. As you said i have tried no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`define` defines constant at runtime so calling `Yii::createWebApplication($config);` after this line makes it undefined in the Yii app.

If you need to call `Yii::app()->baseUrl` there it is not a "constant" anymore.

It's better to use `params` option for the second part of URL so you can call it where needed like:

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->baseUrl . Yii::app()->params->uploadpath . $fileName);
```

You can configure `params` in the main config file.

Comment: 'params' => array(
    'path'      => .Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/upload_folder/',
    'someOption' => true
),   I have added like this and  i called this as                          $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->baseUrl . Yii::app()->params->path . $fileName);     and my web page become empty. nothing is there.

Comment: I am getting this error,                                                                      Property "CAttributeCollection.path" is not defined.

Comment: It should be `'params' => array('path' => '/images/upload_folder/')` and then `$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->baseUrl . Yii::app()->params->path . $fileName);`

Comment: `CException
Property "CAttributeCollection.path" is not defined. ` I am getting the same error still Bizley. It is saved in db but not in upload_folder.

Comment: Show your main config file.

Comment: Use http://pastebin.com/ or something. Or update your question with it.

Comment: You have got `params` declared twice there and the second one at the bottom overwrites the first one.